# Counting one-to-one functions with some restriction

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let $A= \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. What is the number of one-to-one functions $f:A\to B$ such that that $f(i) \neq i$ for all $i\geq 2$ and $f(1)\neq 0,1$?

I tried using derrangements to solve this problem, but I am getting stuck. I have tried using two approaches.

Approach 1: let us say $A$ had one more number (say $0$), so we should derange $6$ of these which will give the answer as $265$. Now, we need to subtract the number of one-to-one functions with $f(0)=0$ as 0 is an additional number that we have added. So I did $265- 5P4= 145$ but that is incorrect (the answer is $256$)

Approach 2: I modified the ranges taking 2 cases. Case 1: one out of $0$ or $1$ is not in range (so the number of possibilities is the number of derrangements of $5$). Case 2: one out of $2,3,4,5$ is not in the range.

I am unable to correctly solve case 2. Any help/suggestion/new method will be very helpful. I would be happy to learn!

Answer (score 1):

We'll consider these cases based on what element is missing from the range.

Case 1: If $0$ is missing from the range, then we just have a derangement of $A$, of which there are $44$.

Case 2: Let $b>0$ be the element missing from the range, and let $a$ be the element with $f(a)=0$. Note that $a$ cannot be $1$.

Case 2a: If $a\neq b$, the consider the function $g:A\to A$ defined by $g(a)=b$, and $g(i)=f(i)$ for all $i\neq a$. Then $g$ is also a derangement of $A$. You can obtain any function $f$ that falls under this case by taking a derangement $g$ of $A$, and then picking one of $2, 3, 4$, or $5$, and sending that element to $0$. There are $44$ ways to choose $g$, and then $4$ ways of picking what gets sent to $0$, so this case has $44*4$ possibilities total.

Case 2b: If $a=b$, then $f$ deranges the elements of $A\setminus a$ and sends $a$ to $0$. There are $4$ choices of which element gets sent to $0$, and then $9$ ways to choose a derangement of the remaining $4$ elements, so this case has $4*9$ possibilities total.

Hence, the answer is $44+44*4+36=256$ possibilities.

Comment: thank you @kevin long